# jQuery - Enable Disable (Toggle) Selectbox onClick Button

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectbox

How can I Toggle a Selectbox between Enable and Disable onClick button...

Scenario:
If I click on `#locked` div, this div should toggle with another class "`icon-unclocked`" and selectbox should be enabled. If I click on "`#locked`" again, selectbox should be disabled and "`icon-unclocked`" has to be removed.

First part (toggleClass) is working great.. but having problem in enable / disable selectbox...

> **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/thhxcmso/)**

Please check the code below...

> **HTML:**

```
<div class="icon-locked" id="locked">&nbsp;</div>
<select class="form-control" id="signontype" disabled>
  <option>Option 01</option>
  <option>Option 02</option>
</select>
```

> **jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#locked" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "icon-unlocked" );
      $('select#signontype').prop('disabled', false);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to check if your locked div contains `pulse-icon-unlocked` class with [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$( "#locked" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "pulse-icon-unlocked" );
    $('select#signontype').prop('disabled', !$(this).hasClass("pulse-icon-unlocked"));
});
```

### [**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/thhxcmso/2/)

Comment: i like this because rather than just toggling enabled/disabled, it ensures that the div pulse-icon_unlocked class is in sync with the enabled/disabled status.

Comment: Wow... **@Dhaval Marthak** this is what exactly I want.. Simple and Perfect.. Thanks... Working like a champ... I am gonna accept your answer... Keep up the good work.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
$("#locked").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("pulse-icon-unlocked");
    $('select#signontype').prop('disabled', !$(this).hasClass("pulse-icon-unlocked"));
});
```

You can check if the `#locked` has class `pulse-icon-unlocked`

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/thhxcmso/4/

Comment: Working like a Champ... Thanks **@Tushar**

Answer (score 3):

You can use

`$('select#signontype').is(':enabled')`

to check whether the selectbox is enabled or not. Based on it you can do what you want.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thhxcmso/9/)

Answer (score 0):

`$("YourElementID").selectbox('disable')` will disable the selectpicker selectbox.

Note: This works fine for *selectbox version 0.2*. I am not sure about latest versions.